# XCode SubProject configuration

Tags: xcode, integration, subproject

due to working needs, I need to integrate an xcodeproj into my existing project as subproject.

The structure of my two projects is the following

[Structure of the two projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZfkW.png)

What is the best practice to integrate (no cocoapods) the subProject into my main project?

I have done the following steps as you can see from the picture below:

[Integration Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikP0c.png)

1. I have copied the folder and all the files to my MainProject
   folder.
2. In XCode I have added files to MainProject and then I have choose
   the "SubProject.xcodeproj" and I can see the structure in the
   project navigator.
3. I have added into the "Search Header Path" the following sentence:
   "${SRCROOT}/../SubProject" with recursive search.

I am not be able to import into my main project the header of the sub project. How can I solve my situation? What I am missing?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean for integration. Which kind of projects are? A simple integration is just to drag the .xcodeproj file of the secondari project into the project navigator of your main project

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear what you mean with "Integrate a sub project". What to you want achieve? A single target or every project should build a different binary?

First of all I would suggest you to put both project in the same folder, in your example they are both inside the `Desktop` folder so this is ok.

As second step you should create a workspace, and add both project to this workspace. There is no need of moving folders around, just drag the project icon inside xCode, just below the workspace icon.